# Sequence vs Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

What is the difference between a sequence and a series and how should they be used i.e. give examples of the usage of these terminologies in separate senarios.

Comment: [Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) and [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 5):

A sequence of real numbers is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$. That is a rule which assigns to each natural number $n$ a real number $a_n$.

Given a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ a series is defined by the sequence of its partial sums. The $n$th partial sum of the sequence $(a_n)$ is $(S_n)$ where $$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k$$

Now, $  \sum_{n= 1}^{\infty} a_n $ is shorthand for $\lim (S_n)$. The sequence $(S_n)$ is generally called a series.

Answer (score 3):

A sequence, by strict definition, is a mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$. Less strictly, it's just a listing of real numbers, $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ For example, $$1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\cdots$$
is a sequence.

A series is an infinite sum of real numbers, so for example, $$1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots$$
is a series.

Comment: Also each term in a series can be represented as a sequence. For example in the above series each term can be represented $T_n=(1/2)^ {n-1}$

Comment: A series doesn't have to be an infinite sum. A finite sum is a series too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29