# How to prove this limit of the sequence $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \left[ \frac{1}{2^i+1}-\frac{(-1)^i}{2^{i+1}-1}\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I was trying to manipulate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}2^{-nk}$, but when we flip the summation sign, in Wolfram Alpha it says that doesn't converges to some value. In fact, if we flip, we will reach in the statement that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}2^k}{2^k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\left[1+\frac{1}{2^k-1} \right]$.

The sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^k-1}$ converges, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}$ diverges, but this sum is known to "result" in $1/2$. If we use this value, and subtract $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^k-1}$ on both sides, we will have that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{2^i+1}-\frac{(-1)^i}{2^{i+1}-1}\right]=\frac{1}{2}$.

So, can we prove that, if we have the series $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \left[ \frac{1}{2^i+1}-\frac{(-1)^i}{2^{i+1}-1}\right]$, it approaches $1/2$ as n approaches infinity?

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%281%2F%282%5En%2B1%29-%28-1%29%5En%2F%282%5E%28n%2B1%29-1%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D) is the limit of $S_n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Sequence or series?

Comment: @imranfat Isn't a series the limit of a sequence?

Comment: For the first step, isn't it $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2^{-n})^k =\frac{1}{2^n-1}$?

Comment: @user No, that is not true. The limit of  Series is a sum, a limit of a sequence is an asymptotic value

Comment: @imranfat Isn’t the partial sum $S_n$ a sequence and isn’t its limit, by definition, the corresponding series?

Comment: Technically, a sequence is a list of numbers separated by comma's. A Series consists of numbers from a sequence in which comma's are replaced by plusses and/or minuses. You can have  finite series or infinite series. Finite series is always convergent (which is a sum). Infinite series depends.  So a convergent Series has a Sum and a convergent Sequence has a limit

Comment: @imranfat Maybe we are referring to slightly different definitions. For the use made here I’m referring to this kind of definition https://math.stackexchange.com/a/956795/505767 which seems fine with the use made by the asker. Thanks

Comment: @user i did an error thx

Comment: In $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\left[1+\frac{1}{2^k-1} \right]$, as $k$ increases, $\frac{1}{2^k-1}$ goes to $0$. So for high values of $k$, the summands are very close to $(-1)^{k-1}$. This series diverges. It will converge under Cesaro summation, but not under ordinary convergence. Remember that one requirement for convergence of any series is that the sequence of summands must converge to $0$.

Comment: @user Fair point!

Comment: @PaulSinclair this is the point. If we use the Cesaro summation we get what I did on the final lines, or not?

Comment: user has provided an answer, but FYI - If a series converges, its Cesaro summation converges to the same limit. So upon proving that $S_n$ converges, and that the Cesaro sum is $\frac 12$, it indeed follows that $\lim_n S_n = \frac 12$. So the main things your approach lacked was just the easy proof that $S_n$ converges, and an explicit discussion of Cesaro summation instead of a vague concept of "results in".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Nice observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, we can't conclude using that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}=\frac12$ since it is true only as a Cesaro mean.

We can proceed, following your idea, using geometric series and flipping indices, as follows

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{2^i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \frac{2^{-i}}{1+2^{-i}}=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k(2^{-i})^k=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k-1}$$

and then

$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \left[ \frac{1}{2^i+1}-\frac{(-1)^i}{2^{i+1}-1}\right]=$$

$$=\frac12- \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}-1}+\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \frac{1}{2^i+1}+\frac{(-1)^{i}}{2^{i}-1}\right]\to\frac12-0+0=\frac12$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh yes of course! I fix that thanks